# How to store a list of values so that it can be accessed in other pages in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have some 10 permission in my table. Some users have all 10 permissions.

Each page in the website have to check whether the user have the particular permission.

In the home page I can do a query and store the permission list to a list box, and check whether Permission1 is in the list box, when I navigate to other page Again I have to check whether the permission is present in the list box.

Here the list box is in home page and I will not be able to access it in page2.
I have to check permission in page load in page 2.

How can I access the list of permission in page2 can I add to session?

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Maybe check out the ASP.NET membership provider? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store your data in the session variable, but I don't like that option at all.  The Session variable relies on keys to extract its values, it is not strongly typed, and if you are load balancing your application, you need a more elaborate way to keep sessions synchronized across servers.

We use for that type of requirement a Class library that contains a Singleton for the particular data we need to retrieve.   The example below will retrieve from the database the list of Permissions only once, and cache it in the singleton.  It is accessible from all your pages.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Singleton that retrieves and stores the common list of permissions.
    /// </summary>
    public static class Permissions
    {
        private static List<String> instance = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the permissions.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        static public List<String> GetPermissions()
        {
            if (instance == null)
                instance = DatabaseHelper.GetPermissionsFromDatabase();

            return instance;
        }
    }
```

This should meet your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

The general way to solve this problem is not to rely on rendered data to a page but to utilize the backing store of the information either directly or though a proxy such as a web service.

So what that means is all of your code that checks those permissions should have some way to access that table that does not rely on the data in the table being on the page.  If you are using asp one approach would be to create a class that represents the permission table and access it from each page.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to run the query on every page, you can use Session state to store the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably store your permissions data in the `Page` object's `System.Web.SessionState.Session` variable.

For example, when the permissions are declared:

```
Page.Session.Add("keyName", "value");
```

When you need to access the information, say in a page load:

```
if(Page.Session.Item("keyName").ToString()=="someValue") //do something
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store in [`Session` state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.aspx) or in [`Application` state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplicationstate.aspx).

`Session` is per user, `Application` is shared for all users (so you have to provide thread synchronization for reading and writing like e.g. the `lock` statement).